# Cloud functions event.params returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app that the users at my work place can use to notify other offices when an application is down. When that happens, the user press a button in the app that updates the Firebase database with flag "red". When updated, I want a notification to the phones to happen, using Cloud functions. The app and Firebase works perfectly, but I want to know what application's status has been updated. I'm trying both event.data.key and event.params.apps, but both returns undefined. What am I doing wrong? Here's the database structure (not allowed yet to post pictures on SO) and Cloud functions code:
Here is picture of database tree:

[Picture of database tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c054U.png)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendAppUpdate = functions.database.instance('medelsappen').ref('/apps/{appar}').onUpdate(event => {

  //Hämtar status för programmet (red/green)
  const snapshot = event.data.val();
  var appStatus = String(snapshot.status);
  var appData = String(snapshot.key);


  //Hämtar vilket program som uppdaterats
  var app = event.params.appar;
  var app1 = String(app);



  console.log("Aktuell app: ", app1, ", Status; ", appStatus, "appData: ", appData);

  var mess = (app1 + " , ny status: " + appStatus);

var topic = "apps";
var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Programstatus uppdaterad",
      body: (mess)
    }
  };

  var options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
  };

admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options)
  .then(function(response) {

    console.log("Lyckades skicka meddelande:", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Fel vid försök att skicka meddelande:", error);
  });

}
);
```

What I want to know is then; How to get the {appar} parameter and include that in the notification? At the moment it just says "undefined" for both variables *app1* and *appData*.

Comment: if you write `var appData = String(snapshot.parent);` what do u get?

Comment: Tried now but that still gives "undefined" in the console, thank's for your answer though. Can it have something to do with the console log error "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" even though the notification is sent?

Comment: You can silence the second warning by returning the Promise from `sendToTopic()`: `return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(...)`

Comment: `appData = String(snapshot.key)` is not correct.  Your DB does not have a field named `key`.  Use `event.data.key`.

Comment: Thank you so much @BobSnyder, it worked! Got the updated app through var appData = event.data.key.